# \useplot with Text in CSV

Tags: tables, csv

Is there a way to import & auto-plot a graph containing text in one column?

Eg. Here's my table

```
Period,Unit Sales (in thousands)
Q1 '07,24943
Q2 '07,27855
Q3 '07,32752
Q4 '07,36766
```

Edit:

Here's what I've tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel = Period,
ylabel = Unit Sales (thousands)]
\addplot table [col sep=comma]{data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a bit trickier than it looks: you need to turn the symbolic input into a number and back again to allow plotting. For example, the following seems to  work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Period,Unit Sales (in thousands)
Q1 '07,24943
Q2 '07,27855
Q3 '07,32752
Q4 '07,36766
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand*{\parseperiod}{}
\def\parseperiod Q#1 '#2\relax{\def\pgfmathresult{0.20#2#1}}
\newcommand*{\parseinvperiod}{}
\def\parseinvperiod #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\relax{\def\pgfmathresult{Q#6 '#4#5}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    x coord trafo/.code = {\expandafter\parseperiod#1\relax},
    x coord inv trafo/.code = {\parseinvperiod#1\relax},
    xticklabel = {\tick},
    xtick = data,
    xlabel = Period,
    ylabel = Unit Sales (thousands)]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma]{\jobname.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The idea here is to parse the horizontal labels and turn them into numbers using the low-level `x coord trafo` key. I've done that by grabbing the quarter and the year, and making them into numbers that read `0.20<year><quarter>`. To actually print the labels, you then have to turn that back into text using `x coord inv trafo`. Ther is also a bit of trickery to only have *x*-axis labels for the data itself (`xtick = data`) and to avoid any parsing of the labels at that point (`xticklabel = {\tick}`).

Comment: And people wonder why I just want to insert a screenshot from Excel :/ ... On a serious note, thank you very much for your effort. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I suspect a better demo is needed for this in the manual: it took a bit of effort! I might ask the package author, at least if there are no better answers than mine.

Comment: Surely a \text{} solution would work? \text{Q1 '07},24943 etc...